# Semiconductor Devices- PN Diode

Tags: semiconductors

Why we use metal contact in PN diode at surface(both end)? We can have directly passed the current without using it.

Is it due to surface recombination velocity? If so then How.

Comment: How do you want to connect the diode to the rest of a circuit?

Comment: Just a battery is connected to diode in forward or reverse bias.

Comment: Connected *how*?

Comment: It is not connected anywhere in the circuit. I just want to know the behavior of diode near the metal contact at end side of diode.

Comment: You need to edit your question to greatly clarify what you want because as it stands, we're all trying to figure out what you're even asking.

Comment: @pintuiitbhi "Why do we use metal contacts" and "What is the behavior of a diode near the contacts" are two very different questions. You should clarify exactly what you are trying to ask.

Comment: "Why do we use metal contacts" -> Because metals have a high conductivity and make nice wires.

Comment: Can you please reword your question. This: "We can have directly passed the current without using it" does not make sense. How can you pass a current without using metal wires? Ion beams in a vacuum maybe?

Comment: @VincePatron meatal here means a plate used to fabricate at end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use a metal contact fabricated directly to the PN junction, an oxide or other surface contaminant will likely prevent you from making good contact with the diode. Fabricating the metal contacts directly onto it and then providing you with leads allows you to easily connect the PN junction to the rest of the circuit.

In the old days, they did make diodes out of point contacts where a semiconductor was just touched with a metal probe to make a schottkey diode.

Near the metal contacts, they usually increase the dopants greatly to enable an ohmic contact to occur between the semiconductor and the metal contact. This increase in dopants greatly increases the conductivity of the semiconductor basically turning it into something as conductive as metal itself.

Comment: I want a mathematical approach and explanation

Comment: Mathematical approach to what? To the fact that the doped silicon is not soldering well?

Comment: @pintuiitbhi Eugene's question stands. A mathematical approach to what?

Comment: @horta During my class lecture professor used boundary condition in P doped side to find the equation of minority charge carrier as a function of position. And he used number of minority charge carrier at metal contact zero and at junction high conc. But How this thing happened?

Comment: @pintuiitbhi I'm still grasping at straws here. Maybe what you're talking about is that at the P/metal contact, the minority carriers go to 0 because metal uses electrons only as the carriers. Your professor was maybe using this as a boundary condition to help solve for minority carriers throughout the P type semiconductor.

Comment: @horta After finding the equation of minority carriers on N and P both side, he plot the curve Ln(I) Vs V characteristic curve in forward and reverse bias . But I am not able to understand the Boundary conditions he apply to solve the differential equation he got?

Comment: @pintuiitbhi I think you need to show what notes you have or simply ask him. All of this should have gone into your question.